# Парсер выдает иероглифы

Tags: python, парсер, parse

Вообще мне нужно парсить буквально одну строку на одной конкретной странице сайта https://steamdb.info
Но html.text выдает просто иероглифы, хотя статус html = 200 (����7�����, такого формата), причем другие сайты выдают нормальный html код

Заметил что такая же шляпа не только со steamdb, а еще с Ютубом и сайтом Lenta.ru

Куда копать :с

Спасибо

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://steamdb.info'
HEADERS = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36 OPR/86.0.4363.70',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="100", "Opera GX";v="86"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'cookie': '',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1'
    }


def get_html(url, params=''):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    r.encoding = 'UTF8'
    return r

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='table-responsive')
    cards = []

html = get_html(URL)
print (html)
print (html.text)
```

Comment: Во первых ваш код выдает <Response [403]>. Во вторых на сайте стоит защита в виде cloudflare.

Comment: `'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',` вот эту строчку уберите. Кодировку это исправит, но врятли поможет Вам распарсить этот сайт с `bs4`

Answer (score 0):

замените `r.encoding = 'UTF8'` на `r.encoding = 'UTF-8'`

Answer (score 0):

Чистый requests автоматически распаковывают только ответы сжатые с помощью gzip. Так как у вас ответ приходит в кодировке с использованием сжатия Brotli,

`'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'`,

то для декодирования нужны сторонние библиотеки brotli или brotlicffi. Смотри в документации requests часто задаваемые вопросы [Закодированные данные?](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/community/faq/#encoded-data)